# Implementing SSL for SharePoint High trust Apps

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, sharepoint-addin, authentication, web-application

I have been struggling to configure an SSL Certificate based environment for hight trust apps in SharePoint 2013. I have on-premises installation of SharePoint 2013 (Enterprise). Following google and msdn articles, I figured out that high trust apps require Client SSL authentication. My app is a provider hosted app and requires an "https" url to be hit when triggered (there is no option for setting "http" url). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: no , there is no option for setting with http url.

Comment: please mark the response as answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use http on high trust app but you can switch it off for debugging to use http!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179901.aspx

also its noted here in another question that i answered!

[Getting 401/403 in High Trust App for Sharepoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79284/getting-401-403-in-high-trust-app-for-sharepoint-2013)

as for the question, refer to the link above from msdn but goto:

**Create a provider-hosted app by using Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012**

you need to make sure you follow it closely as its easy to make mistakes! also if you dont know or too complex that means you need to go back to basics and create a simple high trust app first and then build on top of it!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142381.aspx

(i think you might be talking about ssl in iis?? if you are than that is somthing else!) also refer to this for cert setup:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/53465d30-10b2-48c9-9541-5ade738156b4/how-to-setup-ssl-cert-for-apps?forum=sharepointadmin